# Will this code be evaluated on every iteration?

Tags: java, performance, loops

I have this for-each-loop:

```
for (Component c : container.getComponents()) {
    // Loop code
}
```

Is `getComponents` called on every iteration? Does it make sense to call `getComponents` before the look and only work on a cached array?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, getComponents() will only be called once.

It's the equivalent of:

```
for (Iterator<Component> iterator = container.getComponents().getIterator();
     iterator.hasNext(); )
{
    Component c = iterator.next();
    ...
}
```

From [section 14.14.2 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2):

> The enhanced for statement has the form:
>
> *EnhancedForStatement:*
>
> ```
> for ( VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier: Expression) Statement
> ```
>
> The Expression must either have type Iterable or else it must be of an array type (§10.1), > or a compile-time error occurs.
>   The scope of a local variable declared in the FormalParameter part of an enhanced for 
>   statement (§14.14) is the contained Statement
>
> The meaning of the enhanced for statement is given by translation into a basic `for` 
>   statement.
>
> If the type of Expression is a subtype of `Iterable`, then let I be the type of the 
>   expression `Expression.iterator()`. The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic 
>   `for` statement of the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>    VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = #i.next();
>    Statement
> }
> ```

Comment: Jon, how does the compiler guarantee that getComponents() has no side effects and does not produce something different in each iteration? (e.g., if another thread changes the component?).

Comment: It doesn't... but the translation above is basically what it's defined to do. I'll try to find the JLS reference.

Comment: My bad. I misread the source code. I thought the OP was asking whether the control condition in a for loop gets reevaluated. I didn't notice this was a for-each.

Answer (score 10):

getComponents will be called once, and will return an Iterator.  This iterator will then be called using next() and hasNext() methods.

**Update** Here's a bit more detail in attempt to out *Skeet* Jon Skeet on this answer.

The following program shows how the call to `iterator` is made once, even though there are three items in the collection.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
        public java.util.Iterator<String> iterator() {
            System.out.println("iterator() called");
            return super.iterator();
        };
    };
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");

    for (String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
iterator() called
a
b
c
```

If you run this through a Java decompiler, you'll find the following code:

```
    String s;
    for(Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); System.out.println(s))
        s = (String)iterator.next();
```

Addtionally, since we know from the [JLS 14.14.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third%5Fedition/html/statements.html#14.14.1) that the first section of a for statement is only executed once, we can rest assured that iterator method won't be called multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

[Java LanguageSpecification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2) 14.14.2 says:

> EnhancedForStatement:
>   `for ( VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier: Expression) Statement`
>
> If the type of Expression is a subtype of Iterable, then let I be the type of the expression Expression.iterator(). The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of the form:

```
for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {

        VariableModifiersopt Type Identifier = #i.next();
   Statement
}
```

> Where #i is a compiler-generated
>   identifier that is distinct from any
>   other identifiers (compiler-generated
>   or otherwise) that are in scope (§6.3)
>   at the point where the enhanced for
>   statement occurs.

So the expression is evaluated only once (during initialization).

Answer (score 2):

> Is getComponents called on every
>   iteration?

No. Java's foreach loop is based on the [Iterable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface, and is equivalent to this code

```
Iterator<Component> i = container.getComponents().iterator
while(i.hasNext()) {
    Component c = i.next();
    // loop body goes here
}
```

The only difference is that the Iterator is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that when compiled, it would be translated to be a "long hand" for loop, as in using for(int i = 0 ....

Isn't the foreach loop just a programming time saver with the actual bytecode translation the same as doing it "long hand"??

In short, getComponent() should only be called once

Comment: No, that's not how the foreach loop works (though it's true that getComponent() will be called only once).

Comment: This didn't deserve the -1 (the actual answer you gave is correct, although the assumption prior to it is wrong), so here's a +1.